# how to test WPF forms?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, nunit, window

I'm writing complex application where are server and client application, if i want to add some new window in my application i need to run server, then run client, then login click few buttons before i reach window which i right now developing, it's annoying and takes much time. So now i'm looking for some solution where i can run test which can run only my wpf form using mock for services (so i don't need running server and don't need to login), can click or fire events and check controls appear and act the way i want. 
In this case i can save a lot of time because i dont need to waste time when i try to reach my form by running whole application where i need to use login, search bypass some validation forms and etc.
If there is already simple solution then it will be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the MVVM pattern.

[MVVM for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any kind of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)? It would be easy if so, you could simply create fake version of your heavy service using [mocking framework](http://code.google.com/p/fakeiteasy) with combination of [`#if-else directives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx). Somewhere in your application startup code:

```
ILoginService service;

#if DEBUG
    service = A.Fake<ILoginService>();
    // you could even set up your fakes to return logged user to
    // automate logging in process:
    var userFake = A.Fake<IUser>();
    A.CallTo(() => service.LogIn(A<string>.Ignored)).Returns(userFake);
#else
    service = new RealLoginService();
#endif

var myWindow = new MyWindow();
var viewModel = new ViewModel(service);
myWindow.DataContext = viewModel;

// ...
```

All you need is `ViewModel` (assuming you use such) being able to take `ILoginService` dependency. Then you can mock/fake it up to your liking.